# Error using Polygit.org Polymer elements

Tags: polymer, cdn, polygit

I get the following error using Polymer CDN (Polygit.org):

---

https://polygit.org/components/promise-polyfill/promise-polyfill-lite.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

---

My head tag has the following:

```
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/" />
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="promise-polyfill/promise-polyfill-lite.html">

    <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
    <link rel="import" href="iron-image/iron-image.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-styles/demo-pages.html">
```

Comment: As you are able to load rest of the files successfully this means that `polygit` is not hosting `promise-polyfill`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because polygit.org serves [`taylorhakes/promise-polyfill`](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) and not the fork maintained by [`PolymerLabs`](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/promise-polyfill) as its `promise-polyfill` component.

This can be verified by comparing the [`polygit.org/components/promise-polyfill/bower.json`](https://polygit.org/components/promise-polyfill/bower.json) manifest to the one found in the [`taylorhakes/promise-polyfill`](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill) repository.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated by danielx you have to include `promise-polyfill` from PolymerLabs.

The following line will tell polygit to pull the latest release of `promise-polyfill` from polymerlabs organisation from github:

```
<link href="https://polygit.org/promise-polyfill+polymerlabs+*/components/"
      rel="import">
```